# what should be the approach for pdf generation along with mvc and webapi?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-web-api, tablet

My scenario is I have to make available download link for web, android mobile app and tablet app. where as android and tablet app developers accessing my dot net web API. my web application is in MVC. so what should be approach i should use for this scenario? How can I response as PDF file from my web API ? it is possible?

```
 Edited 1:
    byte[] urlContents = response1.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                string s = GetString(urlContents);
                iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                try
                {
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

                    document.Open();
                    document.Add(new Paragraph(s));
                } 
 return File(stream, "application/pdf", "DownloadName.pdf");.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Edit 2
    var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
                document.SetMargins(20.0F, 20.0F, document.TopMargin + 20, document.BottomMargin);

                var output = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                document.Open();

                StringReader strRdr = new StringReader(htmlString);
                var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(strRdr, null);
                foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
                    document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);

                writer.Flush();
                output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                //document.Close();
                return File(output, "application/pdf","somefilename");
```

Comment: is it regarding .net or  android?

Comment: dot net web api. I am working on it. so i have provide all clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a PDF from a ASP.net WebAPI project (Or any file for that matter) you can return the bytes via byte array in a HttpResponseMessage while setting the ContentDisposition header to "attachment".

For example:

```
    //Web API Controller GET
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
            //Do something here to generate your pdf
            byte[] fileToReturn = pdf.GenerateImagePDF();

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileToReturn);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "SomeFileName";

            return response;
    }

    // MVC Controller Action - Reading the PDF from WebAPI and returning to browser
    public ActionResult SomeAction() {
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync([BuildYourURLtoWebAPIHere]).Result;
        Task<Stream> streamTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        Stream stream = streamTask.Result; //blocks until Task is completed
        byte[] bytes;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        }
         return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
   }
```

If your question was really about generating the actual PDF, then you should search for the many free or commercial PDF libraries.

Comment: Thanks, i am using iTextsharp for generating actual pdf. how to receive this response in my mvc controller action ?

Comment: I would use a BinaryReader to read the stream from the WebAPI into a ByteArray.  Then when you return from your MVC Action return the bytes and set the mime type to application/pdf. 'return File(bpdf, "application/pdf");'

Comment: pls check this may help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828819/net-component-for-conversion-to-pdf

Comment: Thanks guys. but this is generating pure string in pdf. where as my string in formatted html from database. I need its proper rendered format. can you help please. please refer my edited code by what it is made charm.

Comment: That looks like it is from your MVC action... Why are you creating an iText document instance?  I was assuming the PDF was generated in your WebAPI controller.  If that is the case when you read it in your MVC action it is just a bytearray.

Comment: See my edit to see how to read the generated PDF from the WebAPI and return to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but it might reflect direct unformated contents. I tried your edited code. It is showing browser with message "File is loading". where as I need formatted pdf as html format. Please check my Edit 2 Where ItextSharpp generating corrupt file.